# readxl fails to read all columns of excel 1997-2003 workbook

Tags: r, excel, readxl

I am trying to read all EU weekly oil bulletin data files from this source http://ec.europa.eu/energy/observatory/reports, specifically all xls-files with "raw_data" in the file name.

```
library(rvest)
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)

url <- "http://ec.europa.eu/energy/observatory/reports/"
files <- read_html(url) %>% html_nodes("a") %>% .[grepl("raw",.)] %>% html_attr("href")
```

However, read_excel fails to correctly parse all columns of the excel files and returns only the first (date) column. See below example of file 161.

```
t <- tempfile(fileext = ".xls")
download.file(paste0(url, files[161]), t, mode="wb")
data <- read_excel(t)
unlink(t)
```

which just returns

```
A tibble: 126 x 1
`Prices in force on`
<dttm>              
1 2018-03-19 00:00:00 
2 2018-03-19 00:00:00
....
```

I know that I can download all xls-files and convert them to .xlsx or .csv files using excelcnv.exe, but that is relatively slow and it would be good to have a pure R solution. Any idea  how to read all information from the excel files? Many thanks!